# Python with Catalina : No module named 'OpenGL'

Tags: python

I am running the examples provided by the PyQtGraph python graphic module, on a MacOS Catalina. They all work fine for me, except those in 3D. I have a message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/examples/GLVolumeItem.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .GLViewWidget import GLViewWidget
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 2, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'
```

The OpenGL module, though deprecated in Catalina, is present at the location(I checked)

> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework

but I have no clue about how to make python find it. Does anyone have ?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

You need a python library, not the system framework.

The standard OpenGL python library is [PyOpenGL](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL/). However, that seems to be different from the library requested by the code.

If you installed PyQtGraph correctly, that should install everything you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I first installed PyQtGraph via conda, with the negative result I explain in the question. I then tried reinstall it with pip, then pip3, with exactly the same error... :/

Comment: OK, I installed PyOpenGL and now the error message disappear and the example does run (not all of of them but one problem at a time). Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: In this case the op.iz using anaconda so use conda to set up an environment and the python packages needed. Don't use pip or venv